# VB.NET how can I check if String Contains alphabet characters and .?

Tags: regex, vb.net, string

Using visual basic, I have a string. Want to check that the string contains a single, capital alphabetic character followed by a period.  Tried to use Contains as in the following:

someString.Contains("[A-Z].")  but this didn't return me what I wanted.

Also need to check for a single number followed by a period.

How can I do this in Visual Basic

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The logic is a little off in the highest rated answer. The function will only validate the first character and then return true. Here's the tweak that would validate the entire string for alpha characters:

```
'Validates a string of alpha characters
Function CheckForAlphaCharacters(ByVal StringToCheck As String)
    For i = 0 To StringToCheck.Length - 1
        If Not Char.IsLetter(StringToCheck.Chars(i)) Then
            Return False
        End If
    Next

    Return True 'Return true if all elements are characters
End Function
```

Answer (score 15):

Use this function:

```
Function CheckForAlphaCharacters(ByVal StringToCheck As String)


    For i = 0 To StringToCheck.Length - 1
        If Char.IsLetter(StringToCheck.Chars(i)) Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next

    Return False

End Function
```

Usage

```
    Dim Mystring As String = "abc123"
    If CheckForAlphaCharacters(Mystring) Then
        'do stuff here if it contains letters
    Else
        'do stuff here if it doesn't contain letters
    End If
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe I have another way you could check if there was a letter in a string, if thats all you wanted to check. say you have a random string of characters. example "12312H231" the string isnt the same as this because it has a letter in it "12312h231" if you use string.tolower = string.toupper. it will be false if it has a letter, and true if it has numbers only.

```
if string1.toupper = string1.tolower then
'string1 is a number
else
'string1 contains a letter
end if
```

Answer (score 7):

Apparently I cannot vote up or comment here. However, the RegEx answer is by far the simplest and best solution to this problem. For example, if you need to test a string as to whether it is numeric or alpa or alphanumeric or a mix, whatever, this solution accomplishes the task.

Test if a string is numeric use `"[0-9]*"`
Alpha only All Upper Case `"[A-Z]*"`
Alpha only, Mix Case Allowed: `"[A-Z][a-z]*"`
Two digits, One upper case letter, then six lower case letters followed by a single digit that is a '3' or a '7': `"[0-9]{2}[A-Z][a-z]{6}[3,7]"`

For example, this statement tests whether a string begins with two letters and ends with 7 digits: (It is taken from SSRS)

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.ismatch(Fields!YourStringToTest.Value,"[A-Z][a-z]{2}[0-9]{7}")
```

Answer (score 4):

I added a check for whitespace as I am looking at names.  This will not return false if there is a space in your string.

```
    'Validates a string of alpha characters
    Function CheckForAlphaCharacters(ByVal StringToCheck As String)
        For i = 0 To StringToCheck.Length - 1
            If Not Char.IsLetter(StringToCheck.Chars(i)) Then
                If Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(StringToCheck.Chars(i)) Then
                    Return False
                End If
            End If
        Next

        Return True 'Return true if all elements are characters
```

End Function

Answer (score 3):

I have a simple solution. But the solution is not elegant. You can first create string i.e. from "A.", "B.", until "Z.".

So, assume that MyString variable contains the string you wanted to test. You can then test MyString with "A." string by using String.IndexOf method. If the return value is non-negative then "A." existed in MyString. Continue for "B.", "C." until "Z.". You can repeat the same way for integer, i.e. "0.", "1." until "9.".

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use regular expressions. You can check the following regular expression to match alphabets, . and ?

```
([A-Z]|.|\?)
```

I have not tested the above.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a regex to test for this (or google for a regex that does what you need. Then call regex.match

```
Regex.Match(inputString, "regex")
```

Comment: how do I create a regex in Visual Basic?

Comment: just put the regex string in double quotes. Regex is part of the System.Text.RegularExpression namespace.  It takes in two values.  the input string and a string of the regex.

Comment: I tried: Dim rowHeaderRegex As Regex = New Regex("([A-Z]|.|\?)")
         Dim M As Match = rowHeaderRegex.Match(rowName)

It worked for "A. SomeString"  but "1. SomeString" also returned success does it need to be different to exclude numbers?

Answer (score 1):

FYI, In VBA, we need to use Lcase for Lower character and Ucase for upper character

```
If Lcase(String1) = Ucase(String2) then
Msgbox " Numbers"

Else
Msgbox " Alphabets"

End if
```

Answer (score 1):

I find it frustrating to find that this question, which seems to be to be fairly clearly written, if not well-researched, has *ten* not-deleted answers, but *none of which* actually precisely answer the question, not even the accepted answer.

The question is here:

> check that the string contains a single, capital alphabetic character followed by a period. …
>   Also need to check for a single number followed by a period.

The closest is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9278658), but that has two flaws: first, it includes a validation for the `"?"` character for some reason, even though the question didn't ask for that, but more problematically, like most of the other answers, it incorrectly assumes that the input is strictly in the ASCII range, which won't work even for accented Latin characters, never mind characters from other scripts.

The accepted answer, along with two others, verifies that *all* characters in the input are letters, which is not what was asked for, and then also fails to check for upper-case, something that the question *does* ask for.

It is inexplicable to me that so many incorrect answers could have been posted, without there being even one correct answer. But, I intend to rectify that.

Here then are *five* different approaches to the problem (code below)…

The first two make the assumption that any Unicode *letter* that is upper-case may be used, as well as any Unicode *digit*, that the immediately-following character is required to be a `"."` character, and that a string of any length meeting these conditions qualifies. Note that there are "decimal digits" in several different scripts, such as Arabic-Indic, Devengari, Bengali, etc. Likewise, scripts from around the world have the idea of upper- and lower-case, including non-Latin scripts like Cyrillic, Greek, etc.

A properly-localizable solution should take all this into account, and work regardless of the language (and thus script) that the program is using.

Within these first two solutions, there is one that scans the string and examines each character explicitly, and one that uses a regular expression to perform the check. The former is perhaps easier to comprehend, but IMHO the regular expression is more *expressive*, and is not really that complicated.

All that said, sometimes you really do want to restrict the program behavior to supporting Latin scripts only. Thus, the third through fifth solutions I offer. The third is just like the very first solution, but allowing only Latin characters for the upper-case letter and the digit. The fourth and fifth are two different regex-based approaches: the fourth one is a bit easier to write, but requires explicitly stating the character value range for the Latin characters; the fifth one uses the Unicode character block names and lets the `Regex` class figure out the actual character values.

The fifth is more verbose, but I find in this case it's more expressive, in the sense that you can tell why those particular character block ranges were selected. It's also a lot easier to change the restriction. For example, if you wanted only the basic Latin character set, without accented characters, sideways ones, etc. you could just include the `"IsBasicLatin"` value.

Note that both of those regex-based solutions require the use of a "zero-width look-ahead" to perform what is essentially an "and" comparison. I.e. the look-ahead first verifies that the character is in the right script range of characters, and then the main part of the regex then actually checks for upper-case or digits.

This code example also includes sample data and a simple helper method to test each implementation. Note that in the sample data, the second and third string instances that appear to have a capital Latin `A` character, actually has a capital Cyrillic `А` character. Thus, when tested against Latin-character requirement, it will fail the test, while tested against the globalization-friendly implementation that supports all scripts, it will pass.

The sample data also includes a string with an Indic digit `١`. Again, this will pass the globalization-friendly test, but fail the Latin-only version.

Hope this helps!

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8

        Dim values As String() = {"A.", "0.", "aZ.foo", "b9.bar", "É.", "А.", "А!", "e.", "a١.foo", "b0,bar", "é."}

        TestValidateWithValues(values, AddressOf ValidateString)
        TestValidateWithValues(values, AddressOf ValidateStringRegex)
        TestValidateWithValues(values, AddressOf ValidateLatinString)
        TestValidateWithValues(values, AddressOf ValidateLatinStringShortRegex)
        TestValidateWithValues(values, AddressOf ValidateLatinStringVerboseRegex)
    End Sub

    Function ValidateString(text As String) As Boolean
        If text.Length < 2 Then Return False

        For i As Integer = 0 To text.Length - 2
            Dim ch As Char = text(i)

            If (Char.IsLetter(ch) And Char.IsUpper(ch) Or Char.IsDigit(ch)) And text(i + 1) = "."c Then Return True
        Next i

        Return False
    End Function

    Function ValidateStringRegex(text As String) As Boolean
        Return Regex.IsMatch(text, "(?:\p{Lu}|\p{Nd})\.")
    End Function

    Function ValidateLatinString(text As String) As Boolean
        If text.Length < 2 Then Return False

        For i As Integer = 0 To text.Length - 2
            Dim ch As Char = text(i)

            If (IsLatinChar(ch) And Char.IsUpper(ch) Or
                IsLatinDecimalDigit(ch)) And
                text(i + 1) = "."c Then Return True
        Next i

        Return False
    End Function

    Function IsLatinChar(ch As Char) As Boolean
        Return ch >= ChrW(0) And ch <= "ʯ"c ' IsBasicLatin, IsLatin-1Supplement, IsLatinExtended-A, IsLatinExtended-B, IsIPAExtensions
    End Function

    Function IsLatinDecimalDigit(ch As Char) As Boolean
        Return ch >= "0"c And ch <= "9"c
    End Function

    Function ValidateLatinStringShortRegex(text As String) As Boolean
        Return Regex.IsMatch(text, "(?=[\u0000-ʯ])(?:\p{Lu}|\p{Nd})\.")
    End Function

    Function ValidateLatinStringVerboseRegex(text As String) As Boolean
        Return Regex.IsMatch(text, "(?=[\p{IsBasicLatin}\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}\p{IsLatinExtended-A}\p{IsLatinExtended-B}\p{IsIPAExtensions}])(?:\p{Lu}|\p{Nd})\.")
    End Function

    Sub TestValidateWithValues(values As String(), validator As Func(Of String, Boolean))
        Console.WriteLine($"Testing method {validator.Method.Name}:")
        For Each value In values
            Console.WriteLine($"Text: {value}, Result: {validator(value)}")
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

p.s. You'll want your console window font set to something that supports all of the tested characters, such as "Courier New", if you don't want to see a character-replacement glyph instead of the actual character for the `١` character.

Comment: @Poyda:  _"is that not ASCII?"_ -- no, the letter `'A'` is not ASCII. In C#, it's UTF16, and in any case the character point itself can be encoded in _any_ character encoding. Saying the character itself is _any_ particular encoding is simply wrong. In any case, the _question_ does not stipulate `'A'` through `'Z'`...that just happens to be the characters they used in their _failed_ attempt to solve the problem. That's not the _specification_...the specification can be found in the question text before the code example. As far as whether this answer is _"excellent"_ or not, well...

Comment: ... I obviously feel it's a well-written answer and the only one that actually addresses the question that was asked in precise terms. But clearly no one else, including you, has found it useful, never mind _"excellent"_, your comment notwithstanding.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but people still want to know. This is fairly easy. It is important to only pass one character. The function will tell if it alphanumeric and return a boolean answer.

If the character matches what is in the AlphaNumericValidator variable, then it is alphanumeric. No loops. Pretty basic.

```
    Public Function Is_AlphaNumeric(Text As String) As Boolean
    Dim AlphaNumericValidator As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
    Dim b_Result As Boolean

    If InStr(AlphaNumericValidator, Text) > 0 Then
        b_Result = True
    Else
        b_Result = False
    End If

    Return b_Result

End Function
```

Comment: This does not answer the question which was asked.

Comment: @shadowspawn: I agree. Though, it turns out that _none_ of the previously posted answers do, strictly speaking. Most provide enough information for the OP to get to where they needed to be, but I don't feel that _any_ of the actually _answered_ the question. I've [made an attempt to fix that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57129885). :)

Answer (score 0):

> This code is to check whether a string contain A-Z followed by (.) Or 0-9 followed by (.). * asterisk refer to 0 or more characters.

```
Dim text As String = "A.1."
'This if clause will check if string value has range A to Z followed by period or has range 0 to 9 followed by period
If text Like "*[A-Z].*" Or text Like "*[0-9].*" Then
    'Do something
End If
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).